# CoolUtils TotalPDFPrinterX causes ASP C# site to crash

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, pdf-generation

My company has purchased the CoolUtils TotalPDFPrinterX from https://www.coolutils.com/TotalPDFPrinterX

I make an HTTP PUT from Postman to the API and I get “Could not get any response”.

[image: Could not get any response]

When running on my Windows machine the PDF prints fine however on the server the site crashes and in the event log I get the error "A process serving application pool '[MY_APP_POOL]' failed to respond to a ping. The process id was '[MY_PROCESS_ID]'."

[image: A process serving application pool '[MY_APP_POOL]' failed to respond to a ping]

Here is my C# code:

```
PDFPrinterX ppx = new PDFPrinterX();
ppx.Print(fileName, printerName, "-ap Default");
if (ppx.ErrorMessage != null)
{
    WriteToSQL(id, false, ppx.ErrorMessage, 2);
    Console.WriteLine(ppx.ErrorMessage);
}
```

By writing to the event log I know the site crashes on this line: `PDFPrinterX ppx = new PDFPrinterX();` I have also surrounded the above code with a try catch and no exception is thrown.  The site still crashes.

Things I have tried:

- Uninstalling and Reinstalling the CoolUtils software
- Giving EVERYONE Full control to the site folder and the CoolUtils program folder
- Creating a C# desktop application using the same code.  THIS WORKS FINE ON THE SERVER.  It's just the ASP site that crashes.

Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Comment: Check the app pool. what are the version requirements for this tool. there could be a conflict which is only realized when you try to `new` an instance of `PDFPrinterX`. I suggest rechecking the documentation.

Comment: @Nkosi What exactly in the app pool should I check? The App Pool is set to v4.0.30319 which is the latest version.  And unfortunately this product's documentation is almost nonexistent.

Comment: What are the two environment. You say it runs fine on your windows machine. what is the environment of the server? One of their [pages](https://www.coolutils.com/Print-PDF-C-sharp) shows `Win 2000/NT/XP/2003/Vista/7`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Nkosi I was able to find a workaround.

> ActiveX works only with 32-bit internet information server. 64-bit server is not supported. Use command line version instead.

Our IIS server is 64 bit so that is what probably caused the site to hang up.

Buttt... the command line still worked in printing the PDFs on the server.

Client side code (makes the HTTP POST):

```
private void SendToPrinter(string fileName, string printerName, int id, decimal documentSequence)
{
    // use http client to make a POST to the print api
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        // compile the values string to transfer in POST
        // should finish to look something like this:
        // C:\print.pdf&PRTFTW_OFIT&ValShip-155320-1
        var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "", fileName + "&" + printerName + "&ValShip-" + id + "-" + documentSequence},
        };

        // URL encode the values string
        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

        // make the POST

        // DEBUG
        var response = client.PostAsync("http://localhost:54339/api/print", content);

        // retrieve the response
        var responseString = response.Result.ToString();
    }

}
```

Server side code (receives the HTTP POST):

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace api.valbruna.print.Controllers
{
    public class PrintController : ApiController
    {
        // POST api/print
        public HttpResponseMessage Post(HttpRequestMessage request)
        {
            try
            {
                // parse the content recieved from the client
                var content = request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                // decode the content, certain characters such as 
                // '&' get encoded to URL lingo such as '%26'
                content = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(content);

                // split the string into 3 seperate parts
                String[] str = content.Split('&');

                // remove the equal sign from the first string
                str[0] = str[0].Trim('=');

                // compile the arguments command line string
                // should finish to look something like this:
                // "C:\Program Files (x86)\CoolUtils\Total PDF PrinterX\PDFPrinterX.exe" "C:\print.pdf" -p"\\PRINTERS\PRTFTW_OFIT" -ap Default -log "C:\inetpub\logs\CoolUtils\log-ValShip-155320-4.txt" -verbosity detail"
                String arguments = "\"" + str[0] + "\" -p\"\\\\PRINTERS\\" + str[1] +
                                   "\" -ap Default -log \"C:\\inetpub\\logs\\CoolUtils\\log-" + str[2] +
                                   ".txt\" -verbosity detail";

                // file location for PDFPrinterX.exe
                String file = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\CoolUtils\Total PDF PrinterX\PDFPrinterX.exe";

                // start the process
                System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
                System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
                startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
                startInfo.FileName = file;
                startInfo.Arguments = arguments;
                process.StartInfo = startInfo;
                process.Start();

                return new HttpResponseMessage() { Content = new StringContent(content) };
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return new HttpResponseMessage() { Content = new StringContent(e.Message) };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The more I research this thing online the more I'm inclined to say that `ActiveX` which is the **`X`** in `PDFPrinterX` doesn't seem to work well when hosted in IIS.

I've seen a few forums where they say it works fine when they debug on localhost but when deployed to server is crashes.

> ...works fine when used inside localhost(Visual studio)

One of their feature pages shows that it requires Win 2000/NT/XP/2003/Vista/7

You should look into whether your server supports ActiveX components that can work in conjunction with IIS.

Looking at one of their other products support page: [TotalPDFConverterX](https://www.coolutils.com/help/TotalPDFConverter/ConvertPDFonserver.php):

the following note in my opinion may also apply to `TotalPDFPrinterX`, given its dependency on ActiveX as well.

> **Note**: Pay attention to some details during installation Total PDF Converter X:
>
> - Do not forget to register ActiveX in your web-server account.
> - Total PDF Converter X supports only Internet Explorer, Mozilla and Firefox browsers.
> - ActiveX works only with 32-bit internet information server. 64-bit server is not supported. Use command line version instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I will check this when I get back to work on Tuesday.